# Severe neck pain

Tags: management

I work as a driver for a medical daycare in NJ. I lift children with handicap issues on and off the bus. I also drive them to and from their home. I was in severe pain due to a job related injury. My boss said I could not leave unless I found coverage . She also said if I leave that would be considered abandonment of my job?

Comment: Talk to a lawyer.

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace @Anita. Could you clarify what your actual question is in your situation? If you are after situation-specific legal advice note that is something we cannot provide here. Please check the [tour] and [help/on-topic] to learn more about the sort of questions we do cover on this site. "*Were my boss' statements legal?*" is off-topic while "*What constitutes job abandonment*?" or "*Can my boss require me to find coverage myself*?" would be answerable.

Comment: Do **not** trust or rely on that manager.

Comment: Are you part of a union? If yes, have you spoken to your union rep? Have you reported the workplace injury to HR? Have you been to a doctor (and gotten a note from them)?

Comment: @Lilienthal Assuming the question is roughly "what should I do", I believe there are plenty of steps to take following a workplace injury, for taking medical leave and following having said leave rejected, only one of which is to consult a lawyer. I would hope OP already followed a number of those steps prior to reaching this point, but that's far from a given. I would post an answer myself, but I wouldn't call myself anywhere close to an expert on this particular topic.

Comment: I vote to re-open this question. It is *not* off-topic. How can anything be more on-topic about workplaces than on-the-job injuries and how to handle them? In the USA it's not a legal issue or a union issue.  It's a workplace issue. The ways to handle it are spelled out on mandatory posters in the workplace.  (It only becomes a legal issue if the workplace managers refuse to do their jobs after being asked.)

Answer (score 2):

There are workplace standards and regulations for on-the-job injuries. You know those posters full of fine print somewhere in your company's office, maybe in a break room? They say things like "Your rights." Please, please, read them. One of their sections talks about injuries.

And, here's the web site for the New Jersey department of labor. This page describes how to handle workplace injuries. May I suggest you follow the directions in it? https://www.nj.gov/labor/wc/workers/workers_index.html

Your employing company has a *serious* problem if a supervisor demanded that you continue to work after being injured, and threatened you with loss of your job if you didn't keep working. I know this doesn't make your personal situation any easier. But you would be in the right if you pushed back.